# SQL compare each value of column to all values of row from another table

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

I have two tables `StudentTable` and `LevelsTable`. I'm using Java and Sqlite.

my first table : StudentTable

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
| idS| firstName | famillyName |  age      |     pushUps   |     
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 |     a     |      d      |    17     |     20        |
|  2 |     b     |      e      |    18     |     30        | 
|  3 |     c     |      f      |    19     |     50        | 
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+---------------+
```

my second table: LevelsTable

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------------+
| idP| veryWeak  | weak   |  average  |  good  |   veryGood   |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |     10    |   15   |    20     |   30   |     40       |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------------+
```

I want to count the number of students for each level depending on how many pushups do each one.
For example : if i have 1000 students, i want to get a result like that :

- 100 students ∈ [10,15[ --> very weak
- 250 students ∈ [15,20[ --> weak
- 400 students ∈ [20,30[ --> average
- 150 students ∈ [30,40[ --> good
- 100 students > 40      --> very good.

What do you suggest for a solution??

Comment: I dont see the use the 2nd table into the query where you can use the first table and using conditional sum you can get the count, however the values in the conditional sum would be hardcoded as mentioned in the 2nd table.

Comment: Do you want to do this in Java code or in SQL? Your `LevelsTable` is not very convenient for SQL, but it can be done. Can there be multiple records in `LevelsTable`? If so, what does that mean? And what does a value < 10 mean?

Comment: i need the number of each class to use it in bar chart so i'm doing that in Java, and < 10 ∈ very weak too.  @ Andreas

Comment: @ Abhik Chakraborty i use the second table because there are many tests not only pushups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure SQL, you can do it like this:

```sql
SELECT CASE x.studentLevel WHEN 0 THEN 'super-duper weak'
                           WHEN 1 THEN 'very weak'
                           WHEN 2 THEN 'weak'
                           WHEN 3 THEN 'average'
                           WHEN 4 THEN 'good'
                           WHEN 5 THEN 'very good'
       END AS "level"
     , COUNT(*) AS "count"
  FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN s.pushUps >= lvl.veryGood THEN 5
                     WHEN s.pushUps >= lvl.good     THEN 4
                     WHEN s.pushUps >= lvl.average  THEN 3
                     WHEN s.pushUps >= lvl.weak     THEN 2
                     WHEN s.pushUps >= lvl.veryWeak THEN 1
                                                    ELSE 0
                END AS studentLevel
           FROM StudentTable s
              , LevelsTable lvl
          WHERE lvl.idP = 1/*pushUps*/
       ) x
 GROUP BY x.studentLevel
 ORDER BY x.studentLevel
```

---

**Update**

As I mentioned in a comment, your `LevelsTable` is not very convenient for SQL. The table suggested by *Strawberry* in another answer is a step in the right direction, but needs two changes: It needs multiple sets of levels, and the levels should be ranges, with upper and lower boundary.

For multiple sets of ranges, you need a column identifying the set. Let's call that the `levelType`, and to keep it simple and easy to use, let's make it a text column naming the type, e.g. `'pushUps'`.

For the range boundaries, one way is lower- and upper-inclusive, e.g. `0-9`, `10-19`, and so on. That won't work if your values can be floating point, because `9.5` would be between ranges, so it's better to make the boundaries lower-inclusive and upper-exclusive, like you described in the question.

You can keep an `idP` column if you want, but it's not needed.

```sql
CREATE TABLE LevelsTable (
    levelType   VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    lowerLevel  INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    upperLevel  INTEGER      NULL,
    levelDesc   VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_LevelsTable PRIMARY KEY ( levelType, lowerLevel )
);

INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps',  0, 10  , 'pathetic'  );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps', 10, 15  , 'very weak' );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps', 15, 20  , 'weak'      );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps', 20, 30  , 'average'   );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps', 30, 40  , 'good'      );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'pushUps', 40, NULL, 'very good' );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'age'    ,  0, 13  , 'child'     );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'age'    , 13, 20  , 'teenager'  );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'age'    , 20, 55  , 'adult'     );
INSERT INTO LevelsTable VALUES ( 'age'    , 55, NULL, 'senior'    );
```

Now, if you want to list the students and show their level, it's simple:

```sql
SELECT s.idS, s.firstName, s.famillyName
     , s.age, a.levelDesc AS ageLevel
     , s.pushUps, p.levelDesc AS pushUpLevel
  FROM StudentTable s
  JOIN LevelsTable a ON a.levelType = 'age'
                    AND a.lowerLevel <= s.age
                    AND (a.upperLevel > s.age OR a.upperLevel IS NULL)
  JOIN LevelsTable p ON p.levelType = 'pushUps'
                    AND p.lowerLevel <= s.pushUps
                    AND (p.upperLevel > s.pushUps OR p.upperLevel IS NULL)
 ORDER BY s.idS;
```

Output would be:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-----+----------+---------+-------------+
| idS| firstName | famillyName | age | ageLevel | pushUps | pushUpLevel |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----+----------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |     a     |      d      |  17 | teenager |    20   | average     |
|  2 |     b     |      e      |  18 | teenager |    30   | good        |
|  3 |     c     |      f      |  19 | teenager |    50   | very good   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----+----------+---------+-------------+
```

The query for push-up group counts is:

```sql
SELECT lvl.lowerLevel AS "from", lvl.upperLevel AS "to"
     , lvl.levelDesc AS "level", COUNT(*) AS "students"
  FROM StudentTable s
  JOIN LevelsTable lvl ON lvl.levelType = 'pushUps'
                      AND lvl.lowerLevel <= s.pushUps
                      AND (lvl.upperLevel > s.pushUps OR lvl.upperLevel
 GROUP BY lvl.lowerLevel, lvl.upperLevel, lvl.levelDesc
 ORDER BY lvl.lowerLevel;
```

Output would be:

```
+------+----+-----------+----------+
| from | to |   level   | students |
+------+----+-----------+----------+
|  20  | 30 | average   |     1    |
|  30  | 40 | good      |     1    |
|  40  |    | very good |     1    |
+------+----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: that exactly what i'm looking for, thank u so much ^^

Comment: i need your suggestion. In fact, my table LevelsTable contains many tests (pushups, abs, running, flexibility ) , so i want to do the same thing with these tests. any suggestion to do that in one query block?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sqlite, but an approach in MySQL might look like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student_pushups;

CREATE TABLE student_pushups
(student_id INT NOT NULL
,pushups INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);

INSERT INTO student_pushups VALUES
(1,20),
(2,30),
(3,50);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pushup_levels;

CREATE TABLE pushup_levels
(pushup_quantity INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,level VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO pushup_levels VALUES
(0,'pathetic'),
(10,'very poor'),
(15,'poor'),
(20,'satisfactory'),
(30,'good'),
(40,'very good'),
(50,'excellent');
```

The following gives us our ranges...

```
SELECT x.pushup_quantity range_start
     , MIN(COALESCE(y.pushup_quantity,1000))-1 range_end
     , x.level 
  FROM pushup_levels x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN pushup_levels y 
    ON y.pushup_quantity > x.pushup_quantity
 GROUP 
    BY range_start;
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| range_start | range_end | level        |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|           0 |         9 | pathetic     |
|          10 |        14 | very poor    |
|          15 |        19 | poor         |
|          20 |        29 | satisfactory |
|          30 |        39 | good         |
|          40 |        49 | very good    |
|          50 |       999 | excellent    |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

...to which we can join our students, to give our results...

```
SELECT a.*
     , COUNT(b.student_id) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.pushup_quantity range_start
            , MIN(COALESCE(y.pushup_quantity,1000))-1 range_end
            , x.level 
         FROM pushup_levels x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN pushup_levels y 
           ON y.pushup_quantity > x.pushup_quantity
        GROUP 
           BY range_start
     ) a    
  LEFT 
  JOIN student_pushups b
    ON b.pushups BETWEEN a.range_start AND a.range_end
 GROUP 
    BY range_start;

+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| range_start | range_end | level        | total |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
|           0 |         9 | pathetic     |     0 |
|          10 |        14 | very poor    |     0 |
|          15 |        19 | poor         |     0 |
|          20 |        29 | satisfactory |     1 |
|          30 |        39 | good         |     1 |
|          40 |        49 | very good    |     0 |
|          50 |       999 | excellent    |     1 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: 1) Not same levels as question. 2) Not same tables as question. 3) If redefining level table, why not just add `range_start` and `range_end`, so you don't have to construct them? 4) Why make level text unique? 5) No `order by`, so result order is arbitrary.

Comment: @Andreas Someone's grumpy

Comment: @OualidBOUTERBIAT Yes, it's an excellent suggestion. It has the considerable advantage that changes to the database won't necessitate changes to the query.

Comment: @Strawberry Not really, I just think a useful answer should be a little more on point. I mean, you took the time to write all that, so why not make it match question? And adding a simple upper boundary to Level table would greatly simply this query, and most uses of the Level table would be for this purpose, so a little denormalizing would be very appropriate.

Comment: @Andreas. Except for your point about upper and lower bounds, I disagree. Where appropriate, I think a useful answer should offer an insight into the correct use of the system being employed (in this case an RDBMs) rather than perpetuate the user's own misunderstanding. But you have provided your answer, and I have provided mine. Why not leave it at that?

Comment: Sure, OP found it useful. --- Sorry, it won't let me remove down-vote unless you edit the answer. *(Please edit by introducing upper bound and simplifying query, but any edit will allow me to remove down-vote, I think)*

Comment: @Andreas I'll keep it as it is - I deliberately wanted to illustrate the possibility of constructing a query without such a bounding. But if you still want to remove your dv, I'll afford you the opportunity to do so...

Answer (score -1):

Change your levelstable to look more like 
id - - amount - - level 
1  - -  10  - - - - - - veryWeak 
2  - - 15  - - - - - -  weak

Then just write a simple query to select the correct label

Or you could put the levelstable in a java enum and just select the correct label whenever you need it.

```
enum Level{
  VeryWeak(10),
  Weak(15);
  private Integer amount;

  Level(Integer amount) {
    this.amount= amount;
  }
 }
```

Depending on your use case defining these levels in a table might not be required.

Comment: That table is fairly useless for joining. Now, if you added both lower and upper boundary, it would be useful.

Comment: @Andreas Your idea might well be better, but this will work too

Comment: @Strawberry How would you join the value `17` into that table? Can be done, but not very easily, for sure.

Comment: @Strawberry My problem  is  get the number of pushups for each student from the table1 and see in what level (weak, ....)this number  it belongs in table2. this is for to get the number of students in each level.